# How to replace K for thousands and M for Millions in the same column in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R and got stuck in my assignment when couldn't convert the text values to numerical.
I've tried a number of solutions but they are not working.
As an example, when doing the following, I overwrite the first line of code, basically I need to mutate both and then convert it to numbers.

```
fifa$Release_Clause2 = str_replace(fifa$`Release Clause`,"K","000")
fifa$Release_Clause2 = str_replace(fifa$`Release Clause`,"M","000000")
```

Comment: Fixing a problem like this requires users here to see a sample of the input data as well as the code you are using. Could you include the results of `dput(head(fifa))` in your question please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you have data that looks like this:

```
 fifa2 <- data.frame(Value = c("€565K", "€5.65M", "€777777"))
```

you can do this:

```
library(dplyr)
fifa2 %>%
  mutate(Value1 = as.numeric(gsub("[€MK]", "", Value)),
         Value1 = ifelse(grepl("K$", Value), Value1 * 1000, 
                                   ifelse(grepl("M$", Value), Value1 * 1000000, 
                                          Value1)))
    Value  Value1
1   €565K  565000
2  €5.65M 5650000
3 €777777  777777
```

Comment: Hi, is not working ):  All the column went to NA...                                                                                             fifa2$Value <- as.numeric(ifelse(grepl("K", fifa2$Value), 
+                        sub("K", "000", fifa2$Value),
+                        ifelse(grepl("M", fifa2$Value),
+                               sub("M", "000000", fifa2$Value),
+                               fifa2$Value)))
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: Well, post some of **your** data so I can take a look...

Comment: fifa2$Value <- as.numeric(ifelse(grepl("K$", fifa2$Value), 
                       sub("K$", "000", fifa2$Value),
                       ifelse(grepl("M$", fifa2$Value),
                              sub("M$", "000000", fifa2$Value),
                              fifa2$Value)))

Comment: That's **code not data**. I need data to see exactly what went wrong. You can post it using `dput()`. For example, if your dataframe is called `fifa2` you can do: `dput(fifa2[1:10,])`to output the first 10 lines

Comment: Try your code again with this data: `fifa2 <- data.frame(Value = c("2K", "3M", "7777"))`- it works perfectly!

Comment: # A tibble: 10 × 95
    ...1     ID Name     Age Photo   Nationality Flag    Overall Potential Club  `Club Logo`  Value Wage  Special
   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <chr>   <chr>       <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl> <chr> <chr>        <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
 1     0 158023 L. Me…    31 https:… Argentina   https:…      94        94 FC B… https://cdn… €110… €565K    2202

Comment: Sorry, that's not processable... Please use dput() as described earlier

Comment: > dput(fifa[1:1,])
structure(list(...1 = 0, ID = 158023, Name = "L. Messi", Age = 31, 
    Photo = "https://cdn.sofifa.org/players/4/19/158023.png", 
    Nationality = "Argentina", Flag = "https://cdn.sofifa.org/flags/52.png", 
    Overall = 94, Potential = 94, Club = "FC Barcelona", `Club Logo` = "https://cdn.sofifa.org/teams/2/light/241.png", 
    Value = "€110.5M", Wage = "€565K", Special = 2202, `Preferred Foot` = "Left", 
    `International Reputation` = 5, `Weak Foot` = 4, `Skill Moves` = 4, 
    `Work Rate` = "Medium/ Medium",

Comment: `Body Type` = "Messi", `Real Face` = "Yes", 
    Position = "RF", `Jersey Number` = 10, Joined = "Jul 1, 2004", 
    `Loaned From` = NA_character_, `Contract Valid Until` = "2021", 
    Height = "5'7", Weight = "159lbs", LS = "88+2", ST = "88+2", 
    RS = "88+2", LW = "92+2", LF = "93+2", CF = "93+2", RF = "93+2", 
    RW = "92+2", LAM = "93+2", CAM = "93+2", RAM = "93+2", LM = "91+2", 
    LCM = "84+2", CM = "84+2", RCM = "84+2", RM = "91+2", LWB = "64+2", 
    LDM = "61+2", CDM = "61+2", RDM = "61+2",

Comment: RWB = "64+2", LB = "59+2", 
    LCB = "47+2", CB = "47+2", RCB = "47+2", RB = "59+2", Crossing = 84, 
    Finishing = 95, HeadingAccuracy = 70, ShortPassing = 90, 
    Volleys = 86, Dribbling = 97, Curve = 93, FKAccuracy = 94, 
    LongPassing = 87, BallControl = 96, Acceleration = 91, SprintSpeed = 86, 
    Agility = 91, Reactions = 95, Balance = 95, ShotPower = 85, 
    Jumping = 68, Stamina = 72, Strength = 59, LongShots = 94, 
    Aggression = 48, Interceptions = 22, Positioning = 94, Vision = 94, 
    Penalties = 75, Composure = 96, Marking = 33,

Comment: StandingTackle = 28, 
    SlidingTackle = 26, GKDiving = 6, GKHandling = 11, GKKicking = 15, 
    GKPositioning = 14, GKReflexes = 8, `Release Clause` = "€226.5M", 
    WageK = 565, ValueK = 110.5, Release_ClauseK = 226.5, WageK2 = 565, 
    ValueK2 = 110.5, Release_ClauseK2 = 226.5), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: The format of your columns is not accepted in R: column names must be contiguous strings, while you frequently have strings interrupted by whitespace

Comment: Also you seem to have values such as "€565K". The currency symbol must be removed before any conversion to numeric! (Otherwise you'll get NA)

Comment: What's more you also have decimal values. Please see edited solution that takes care of the issues.

Comment: It worked, I'll remember you when I create the new facebook! Thank you so much!